Not geting detection from loaded anpr model
I am new to this tensor-rt concepts so I will explain I have been doing.
I am loading anpr model and it is been loadede.The detection is happening on the given source (image/video) but bounding box is not accurate and once detection happened the same detection continues the other frames of the video and images.
from the following [link]
(https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/creating-a-real-time-license-plate-detection-and-recognition-app/)
I have downloaded the pre-trained model and I have created engine locally on system so I have been loading this engine file and doing the anpr detection.
I have giving the complete source code and it's output.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <NvInfer.h>y
#include <NvInferRuntime.h>
#include <NvInferRuntimeCommon.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Logger : public nvinfer1::ILogger
{
    void log(Severity severity, const char* msg) noexcept override
    {
        if (severity != Severity::kINFO)
        {
            std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        }
    }
} gLogger;

std::vector<char> loadEngine(const std::string& engineFile)
{
    std::ifstream file(engineFile, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening engine file: " << engineFile << std::endl;
        return {};
    }
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::vector<char> engineData(size);
    file.read(engineData.data(), size);
    return engineData;
}

void preprocess(const cv::Mat& frame, float* inputData, int width, int height)
{
    cv::Mat resized;
    cv::resize(frame, resized, cv::Size(width, height));
    resized.convertTo(resized, CV_32FC3, 1.0 / 255);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels(3);
    cv::split(resized, channels);

    for (int c = 0; c < 3; ++c)
    {
        std::memcpy(inputData + c * width * height, channels[c].data, width * height * sizeof(float));
    }
}

void postprocess(const float* outputData, int numDetections, cv::Mat& frame, float scoreThreshold = 0.5)
{
    int frameWidth = frame.cols;
    int frameHeight = frame.rows;

    for (int i = 0; i < numDetections; ++i)
    {
        // Assuming output format is [batch_id, x_min, y_min, width, height, score, class_id]
        float x_min = outputData[i * 7 + 1]; // x_min
        float y_min = outputData[i * 7 + 2]; // y_min
        float width = outputData[i * 7 + 3]; // width
        float height = outputData[i * 7 + 4]; // height
        float score = outputData[i * 7 + 5];  // score
        int classId = static_cast<int>(outputData[i * 7 + 6]); // class_id

        // Apply score threshold to filter out low-confidence detections
        if (score < scoreThreshold)
            continue;

        // Convert normalized coordinates to pixel coordinates
        int x1 = static_cast<int>(x_min * frameWidth);
        int y1 = static_cast<int>(y_min * frameHeight);
        int x2 = static_cast<int>((x_min + width) * frameWidth);
        int y2 = static_cast<int>((y_min + height) * frameHeight);

        // Ensure bounding box coordinates are within frame dimensions
        x1 = std::max(0, x1);
        y1 = std::max(0, y1);
        x2 = std::min(frameWidth - 1, x2);
        y2 = std::min(frameHeight - 1, y2);

        // Draw bounding box
        cv::rectangle(frame, cv::Point(x1, y1), cv::Point(x2, y2), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);  // Green bounding box

        // Display detection info
        std::cout << "Detection: Class " << classId << " Score " << score
                  << " Box: [" << x1 << ", " << y1 << ", " << x2 << ", " << y2 << "]" << std::endl;

        // Optionally, display the class label and score on the frame
        std::string label = "Class: " + std::to_string(classId) + " Score: " + std::to_string(score);
        cv::putText(frame, label, cv::Point(x1, y1 - 10), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string engineFile = "model_b1_gpu0_int8.engine";  // Replace with your .engine file path
    std::vector<char> engineData = loadEngine(engineFile);
    if (engineData.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load the engine file." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    nvinfer1::IRuntime* runtime = nvinfer1::createInferRuntime(gLogger);
    if (!runtime)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create TensorRT Runtime." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    nvinfer1::ICudaEngine* engine = runtime->deserializeCudaEngine(engineData.data(), engineData.size());
    if (!engine)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to deserialize CUDA engine." << std::endl;
        delete runtime;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Successfully loaded and deserialized the engine!" << std::endl;

    nvinfer1::IExecutionContext* context = engine->createExecutionContext();
    if (!context)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create execution context." << std::endl;
        delete engine;
        delete runtime;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::VideoCapture cap("/home/Desktop/1.mp4"); // Replace with 0 for webcam
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        delete context;
        delete engine;
        delete runtime;
        return -1;
    }

    const int inputWidth = 256;  // Set according to your model's input size
    const int inputHeight = 256;  // Set according to your model's input size
    const int numChannels = 3;     // Number of channels for the input
    float* inputData = new float[inputWidth * inputHeight * numChannels]; // Input buffer

    const int maxDetections = 100; // Maximum number of detections
    const int outputSize = maxDetections * 7; // Each detection has 7 values (x, y, width, height, score, classId)
    float* outputData = new float[outputSize]; // Output buffer

    void* buffers[2];  // Input/output bindings

    while (true)
    {
        cv::Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // Capture frame-by-frame
        if (frame.empty())
            break;

        preprocess(frame, inputData, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        // Set up input and output bindings
        buffers[0] = inputData;
        buffers[1] = outputData;

        // Use executeV2 for implicit batch engines
        if (context->executeV2(buffers) != 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Inference execution failed." << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        postprocess(outputData, maxDetections, frame); // Call postprocess with number of detections

        cv::imshow("Frame", frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
    }

    // Cleanup
    delete[] inputData;
    delete[] outputData;
    delete context;
    delete engine;
    delete runtime;
    cap.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
} 

OUTPUT
Deserialization required 3363 microseconds.
Successfully loaded and deserialized the engine!
Total per-runner device persistent memory is 0
Total per-runner host persistent memory is 121808
Allocated activation device memory of size 10444800
CUDA lazy loading is enabled.
3: [executionContext.cpp::executeV2::1039] Error Code 3: API Usage Error (Parameter check failed at: runtime/api/executionContext.cpp::executeV2::1039, condition: !mEngine.hasImplicitBatchDimension()
)
Detection: Class -2147483648 Score 5.56482e+10 Box: [61840, 140589, 1279, -2147483648]
Detection: Class -2147483648 Score 1.83698e+28 Box: [0, 0, -2147483648, -2147483648]
Detection: Class -2147483648 Score 4.4091e+24 Box: [0, 0, -2147483648, -2147483648]
Detection: Class 865326016 Score 3.47808e+09 Box: [0, 0, -2147483648, -2147483648]
Detection: Class 48 Score 195.263 Box: [1060603840, 9136671, 1279, 719]
Detection: Class 12 Score 3.00392 Box: [59, 133, 1015, 719]


Please guide me what I have done wrong in code and how can I change.
